# Create all possible combinations by selecting n elements and assigning them to different groups with conditions

Tags: python, filter, combinations

I would like to find a viable way to create all possible combinations by selecting n elements and assigning them to different groups with conditions in Python.

Basically, there are three lists, one list of teacher, one list of guide, and one list of children. They will need to form three travel groups with one teacher and one tour guide from the list and 5 children each team.

```
teacherlist = ["Ms.Tam", "Ms.Gomez", "Mr.Joan"]
guidelist = ["guideA","guideB", "guideC"]
childrenlist = ["0001","0002,"0003",..."0015"]

group1 =[]
group2 =[]
group3 =[]
```

they are to be assigned to three separate groups with equal number subject to the following conditions

1. each team must have at least one teacher and one guide
2. some children do not get along with each other , such as 0002 and 0004, so they cannot be in the same group
3. some children are in the same family, such as 0001 and 0014, so they must be in the same group
4. some children such as 0001 cannot be assigned to group 2

**The goal is to create all possible combinations of three travel groups that satisfy these conditions and print them accordingly.**

I have looked through codes about itertools products and combinations and have no idea where and how should I start.

Condition 4 is particularly tricky because aside from checking the conditions within group, I would also need to check the conditions among group

Thanks a lot in advance for any suggestions and inspirations!

Comment: A super naive solution would be to use the `itertools` functions and create all possible combinations and iterate through, increment a counter if the combination is valid, and that should be the answer.